# Determine man's falling with android device

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

My Samsung galaxy S2 has an accelerometer and gyroscope. With these 2 sensors I need to determine a man's falling. How do I implement it in the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant data is here: [SensorEvent values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values).

1. Acceleration coordinates are relative to phone. So if phone is turning while falling than acceleration vector would "rotate". To normalize it you'd need to also use gyroscope data.
2. You trying to detect speed in some direction. Look at [motion equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion). You'd basically need to integrate acceleration over time. (You'd already need to have normalized acceleration as described above).

I don't know the context of your "man falling", but you might also look at [Free Fall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall) info.

Answer (score 2):

The accelerometer is the only `Sensor` you need to determine a fall: the gyroscope has no use here as the device have a random orientation during the fall and may be rolling.

In absolute free fall the accelerometer returns an accleration value of `(0, 0, 0)`, so when the cellphone starts falling, the value is close to that. Up to you to determine the ceil that triggers the "fall mode".

You can find more on the accelerometer on [that page](http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499.html).

*Edit, further to the comments below:*

- When lying on a table, tilted or not, the accelerometer returns the vector G (the [decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Decomposition) on the various axis is depending of the tilt).
- And during the fall, an acceleration rotating over the axis can be detected if the device is turning on itself. This means the fall detection system should be done over the time unless the acceleration is very close to (0,0,0).

Comment: When device is still will also give you (0,0,0).

Comment: Also, if phone is turning while falling, that would impact (x,y,z) values of acceleration vector. So gyroscope would need to be taken into account.

Comment: when the device is still, the module of the sensor vector is G. In free fall, it will be 0. Upon impact, it will be a lot. I think basically anything beyond 2G can be considered a fall. (or the user throwing his phone to the wall)

Comment: @Peter When still (I assume you mean lying on a table, even if tilted) the vector includes the gravity. When turning you have an acceleration that rotates over the axis, and that can be detected with no gyro. But it is true I should have mentioned it.

Comment: @Shlublu : you are right. When still accelerator shows g, 9.81.

Comment: Thx @Peter. Nevertheless, your answer was interesting as it was pointing to valuable information about free fall and to the official documentation. Why not undeleting it? It could be useful to Zane and others.